# How to get wrong values when executing MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say that I have this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    students_results
WHERE   full_name LIKE '".trim($_POST['full_name'])."'
 AND mother_name LIKE '".$database->escape_value(trim($_POST['mother_name']))."'
 AND birthday = '".$database->escape_value($_POST['year2'])."'"
```

I need to display a message for the vistor to tell him that he entered a wrong name or wrong mother name or wrong year.

Now, I display a message for the user that he entered wrong values, I want to display detailed information about what wrong values he entered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't entirely understand what your question is - you will need to check those values before you execute the query, and show the message

Comment: for example, if the user entered wrong name and year, mother name are right, I want to tell him that you entered a wrong name. How I can do that?

Comment: As an aside, make sure to use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (or some facsimile) when placing `_GET`/`_POST` variables in a query. This is a good way to get a [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) if you don't validate what makes it to the database. (this is in regards to your $_POST['fullname'], btw)

Comment: @Brad Christie: thanks, I know that but now I want to solve the mail proplem.

Comment: why don't you escape full_name?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Because s/he "knows that" already.

Comment: Well, assuming that this is some kind of security validation step, you shouldn't tell them which is incorrect.  Otherwise you're confirming the validity of the other information and making it easier for them to either brute-force or make educated guesses.  It makes the user's life slightly harder, but also aids preventing unwarranted access...

Answer (score 3):

Ok. Somewhat cumbersome:

```
SELECT
    IF(`full_name` = ?,1,0)
  | IF(`maiden_name` = ?,2,0)
  | IF(`birthday` = ?,4,0)
    AS `correctness_mask`
WHERE
      `full_name` = ? 
   OR `maiden_name` = ?
   OR `birthday` = ?
HAVING 
   `correctness_mask` != 0
```

If, for a retrieved row, `correctness_mask` is 7 (`1 | 2 | 4`), you've got the right row. For all other rows, you'll have to check, whether in that mask, the appropriate bit is set.

Note the question marks in the query, by the way. It's my implicit hint to you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) rather than interpolating `$_POST` values directly into your query string.

Comment: Argh. Too late. Got a downvote already. I just figured the `HAVING` clause to be superfluous...

Comment: Can you provide full example for this query in PHP code because I don't know to apply this query with PHP code.

Comment: @SzamDev Every nerve in me screams to not do it. I believe there's a good chance you'd just C/P it, not knowing what it is/does. Why don't you read up on the prepared statements link, try out and afterwards update your question with what you've tried?

Answer (score 2):

> How to get wrong values when executing
>   MySQL query?

**You can't.**

Take the example of two `John Smith`s, one born 1/1/70 with a mother named Ann, and one born 1/1/80 with a mother named Alice.

When the older John Smith enters 1/1/70 and Alice, how will you know it's not the younger John Smith entering the wrong birthdate?

You couldn't be certain.

Comment: I was gonna say something similar. Even if you found a way to figure out which values might be "wrong," telling that to a user would basically give them a way to query your data set and learn much more than what you think you are telling them...

Comment: @Svemir: Agreed. ircmaxell explains (in the question comments) that if something like this were used for security, it would be bad form to tell the user which info is wrong because you are, in effect, also telling them which info is right. Plus, they can focus their brute force attempts on the wrong fields only, saving time.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged php.  You should use [Php Mysql Ref.](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) to send the result to the DB and then determine if you got a result back out.  You can display whatever message you want to the user with a mysql_fetch_row, and a couple if's.

Comment: And the point of this answer is?  What information does it provide other than a link to docs (which aren't really relevant anyway)...?

Answer (score 0):

If `Students_results` table holds the students name, mothers name, the birthdate then I think the database isn't normalized enough. Normalizing could solve your problems too. You can use a student_id to identify the correct row instead of a composite combination of name + mother name + bdate.